# How to fix "Inner Join Group-By" question

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, inner-join

Trying to run a query to pull back no duplicate lines. Currently when running this script I get an error back from Oracle saying

> "ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression"

Tried removing different select rows.

```
SELECT QUEUE_NAME, ITEMS_IN_QUEUE, CREATION_USR_ID
  FROM IN_WF_QUEUE B
  INNER JOIN IN_WF_ITEM A
     ON A.QUEUE_ID = B.QUEUE_ID    
    AND B.QUEUE_NAME LIKE '__________ %'       
    AND (A.QUEUE_START_TIME < (select sysdate from DUAL)-1000)    
  GROUP BY B.QUEUE_ID;
```

Thank you in advance for any help on this issue.

Comment: Hint:  You have one column in the `GROUP BY` and three unaggregated columns in the `SELECT`.

Comment: (Obviously,) This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Read an introduction/manual re the parts of the language you use before you use them & before you ask a question about having used them.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove duplicates, why don't you use `DISTINCT`? That's more *natural* than using `GROUP BY` without any aggregates.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       queue_name, items_in_queue, creation_usr_id
  FROM in_wf_queue b
  INNER JOIN in_wf_item A
     ON A.queue_id = b.queue_id    
    AND b.queue_name LIKE '__________ %'       
    AND A.queue_start_time < sysdate - 1000;
```

Also, there's no need to select `SYSDATE` from dual; it is a function that can be used *standalone*, as in my example. Note that it returns both date and time, so - maybe you'd want to remove time component by truncating it, i.e. use `trunc(sysdate)`. Subtracting 1000 from it means "1000 **days** ago"; just saying, to avoid possible confusion.